# Parameterizing a query with a varying amount of WHERE clause conditionals

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

Let's imagine we have a table containing columns for 'color' and for 'size'. I have a list with color-size combinations (e.g. `[(red, small), (blue, medium)]`), of which the length is unknown. The table should be filtered based on this list, so that the result contains only the rows where the combinations apply.

A query based on the example would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items WHERE ((color = 'red' AND size = 'small') OR (color = 'blue' and size = 'medium'));
```

Parameterizing this query wouldn't work of course, since the amount of combinations varies.

Is there a way to achieve this using the parameterized queries like the ones that are use in [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries)? The only solution I can think of is using string interpolation, which doesn't appear to be a safe.

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a temporary table with two columns `color`, `size`; insert the combinations there first, then make your `SELECT` using `JOIN` with said table

Comment: @JoshPart Hmm, that sounds like it could work. The only issue that I might see arising is that when this query is repeated at the same time (e.g. using connection pooling), combinations outside of the list (from another execution) are added to this temporary table, which would mean that the `SELECT` will return unintended results. Or would wrapping it all in a transaction take care of that?

Comment: Temporary tables are by default per session so each session(connection) would have it's own table. You can use `ON COMMIT` from here [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) to change that to be based on transactions within a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like good scenario for `IN` operator

```sql
select * from items where 
(color, size) in (('red','small'), ('blue','medium'))
```

and it can be parametrized using arrays

```sql
select * from items where 
(color, size) in (
  select unnest (array['red','blue']), unnest(array['small','medium']))
```

First array is for colors, second for sizes. Unnest in one select create pairs.Arrays should have the same number of elements.

And arrays can be passed as parameters to query.

Comment: You don't actually need the `values` clause